# How to speed-up (avoid) django boot time when running tests?

Tags: django, django-testing

When I write django tests, I frequently run then `manage.py test` command.

To increase test run performance I'm aware of `--keepdb` and `--parallel` options.
I'm also aware of being able to run a specific test by targeting it.

I usually run something like this : `manage.py test myapp.tests.test_file.MyTestCase.test_my_test --keepdb`

The problem is that each time I run the command, `django` took few seconds (around 10 seconds in the current project) just to boot-up and start processing the tests.

So during a test development I have to wait 10 seconds each time whereas the test itself took 1 second.

There is a way to enter a sort of "test mode" which keep django booted-up ? So that I can run tests without to wait for 10 seconds boot time after each code modification.

Comment: Have you run `manage.py tests` under a profiler (preferably one that shows a timeline) to see where it's spending that time?

Comment: (Also, did you mean `manage.py test`..?)

Comment: After running through `cProfile`, I see that most of time is passed by initializing `strawberry` GraphQL schema. I don't really care this took time at boot time. I'm seeking for a way to not have to reboot django each time I want to run a test

Comment: There's no 100% perfect way to reload a single module (or a single module and all modules it depends on) in Python that I know of, which would be a prerequisite for that.

Comment: Anyway, if building the schema is the bottleneck and you're willing to try and solve _that_, you could try using a pickle-on-disk-cached version of it when you're developing locally.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, sadly the schema object is not pickable (`Can't pickle local object 'ScriptMagics._make_script_magic.<locals>.named_script_magic'`). Therefore strawberry rely of class decorators to build schema. I would have to ensure the modules aren't imported elsewhere.

Comment: @fabien-michel would you be ok with reporting some of the findings of the cprofile on strawberry's github repo? :) would love to see if we can optimize the code

Comment: done: https://github.com/strawberry-graphql/strawberry/issues/2403